# A little one. Can you find it?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, music

Which piece of music does the below picture represent?

[image: score]

Hint:

> More specifically: It represents the start notes of a famous music piece.

Comment: Good grief, another Morse code puzzle! +1

Comment: If someone can't resolve the details of your image, they don't stand a chance of working your puzzle out. So a -1 from me. Quite apart from `[enigmatic-puzzle]` which is just an attempt to justify inadequate cluing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you find it? I found

> EINE KLEINE NACHTMUSIK (1st Movement)

Explanation:

The music tag and title "A little one..."

> bring to mind the musical piece "[Eine Kleine Nachtmusik](https://musescore.com/classicman/mozart-k-525-1st-movement)", or "A Little Night Music".

As 135 noted in a comment, this does indeed

> look like Morse Code.
>  Extending the "bar" lines in red and reading out the dashes and dots which they cross in fact gives the note letters to the famous opening theme:
>  G, D G, D G D G B D. C, A C, A C A F A D.
>   [image: morse code image]
>  *EXCEPT* there are 5 extra dots after the last "F" which   need to be explained...
>  Good observation from caP: perhaps the dots were intended to indicate that the F is sharp. Treating them as 'is' gives 'Fis', an indicator of F# in languages such as German, appropriate for the song choice.
>  And of course the tall symbols clue the quarter notes, the rest eighths.

Comment: Nice. rot13(V oryvrir gur S fubhyq or funec fb znlor gubfr qbgf ercerfrag gung fbzrubj)

Comment: Aha, [in many languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_note) rot13(Svf zrnaf S funec)

Comment: @caPNCApn, you're right. I am not a native English speaker, I just assumed that rot13(Svf) was also known in English. Have to do my research better next time :)

Comment: @Amoz, correct! You have not mentioned why some notes are bigger than other, but that should be obvious by now. Good job!